Ubuntu 24.04 - no sound on Acer Swift Go Ultra 7 155H/32GB/1TB
I've installed Ubuntu 24.04 on my Acer Swift Go laptop from this year. System fails to detect soundcard and displays only Dummmy Output in the sound settings.
I've added to /etc/modprob.d/alsa-base.conf
options snd_hda_intel model=auto -> it didn't help
I've installed https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin -> v2.2 - didn't help
lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
returns
Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P HD Audio Controller
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Meteor Lake-P HD Audio Controller
Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_mdi
cat /proc/asound/cards -> no soundcards
I wanted to get away from Windows.
Does anyone have any suggestions? I already tried like dozen suggestions found online and none helped. I can also add more information, just let me know what I should do.
Many thanks in advance
Edit.
Small progress
I've editted /etc/default/grub with
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1"
And run sudo update-grub
Afterwards aplay -l and cat /proc/asound/cards display my sound card.
Next I ran sudo apt install pavucontrol and in the settings I've changed Built-in Audio to Pro Audio.
Thanks to that I see Built-in Audio Pro in my sound settings instead of Dummy Output.
Afterwards sound is recognized but works only with external speakrs or headphones. Doesn't work with internal speakers in the laptop.
